# Spring Security: authentication details are null in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-session

Trying to combine Spring Session (to Redis) with Spring Security (DB-based). Authentication works just fine, and if I add listener:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessListener implements ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {


    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        System.out.println("authentication: " + authentication.getName());

        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpSession currentSession = attr.getRequest().getSession();
        System.out.println("session: " + currentSession.getAttribute("SESSION_DETAILS"));
    }
}
```

Then it nicely prints:

```
authentication: admin
session: app.session.SessionDetails@694daf33
```

And Redis store is updated as well:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "spring:session:sessions:c7b0fc2c-3148-4895-9aef-78dfc8443585"
2) "spring:session:expirations:1523615100000"
3) "spring:session:sessions:expires:02acfbd4-93e7-44dc-9b61-38473a8a9ae7"
4) "spring:session:sessions:expires:c7b0fc2c-3148-4895-9aef-78dfc8443585"
5) "spring:session:index:org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME:admin"
```

But when I do in `@Controller`:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Principal principal, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println("authentication: " + authentication.getName());

    ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    HttpSession currentSession = attr.getRequest().getSession();
    System.out.println("session: " + currentSession.getAttribute("SESSION_DETAILS"));

    return "index";
}
```

Then I see the following:

```
authentication: null
session: app.session.SessionDetails@1225ad92
```

New session is created and that is OK, but authentication details are gone. Which is a big surprise, as security configuration allows only authorized requests:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll();
}
```

To sum things up, I see secured content, but authorization details are set to null. How come?

Answer (score 3):

Found a resolution. Even if your `CustomUserDetails` class implements `Serializable` and created in a way:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    Optional<User> optionalUsers = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    optionalUsers
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found"));
    return optionalUsers
            .map(CustomUserDetails::new).get();
}
```

Then Spring Secruity requires `User` also implement `Serializable`. Don't ask me why. Magic.